# Get App Names/Urls Requesting Rss Feed C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a site that has an Rss feed, and this feed is consumed and redisplayed on a number of different sites.

Everytime the RSS feed is requested, I want to get the Url of the website requesting and re-displaying it. I have tried using 'Request.UrlReferrer' but this does not work?

I hope this makes sense, but to break it down.

**Site A has the RSS feed**

**Site B reads in the RSS feed and does something with it**

I want to catch the Url of Site B and store it in Site A somewhere so I can see what websites are using the RSS feed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`Request.UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) property on site A to get the IP of the client sending the HTTP request.

Of course if you are running in a web farm and your web servers are behind a load balancer or a proxy this will give you the IP address of the load balancer and not the client. Hopefully your proxy server is configured to use the [`X-FORWARDED-FOR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) HTTP request header which ports the original client IP address. So if this is your case you could use `Request.Headers["X-FORWARDED-FOR"]`.

Depending on your requirements, yet another possibility is to simply exploit the IIS log files on Site A which contain all requests and their client IP addresses.